# Eager load three way pivot table Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot

I am struggling to get eager loading working in Laravel when working with a three way pivot table. The database is set up as follows:

```
+-------+--------+-------+-------------+
| deals | venues | users |   redeems   |
+-------+--------+-------+-------------+
| id    | id     | id    | deal_id     |
| title | name   | name  | user_id     |
|       |        |       | venue_id    |
|       |        |       | redeemed_at |
+-------+--------+-------+-------------+
```

Where `redeems` is obviously the pivot table. The user model look like this:

```
<?php

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The deals redeemed by the user.
     */
    public function deals()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Deal::class, 'redeems')
            ->withPivot(['venue_id', 'redeemed_at']);
    }
}
```

This allows me to do this:

```
$users = Users::with('deals')->all();
```

And then I get a nice overview of the user and all the deals that they have redeemed in a structure like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Diederik",
  "deals": [
    {
      "id": 33,
      "title": "Deal Title",
      "pivot": {
        "user_id": 1,
        "deal_id": 33,
        "venue_id": 50
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I would like to add the venue information by eager loading it instead of querying the `$user->pivot->venue_id` afterwards.

I tried setting up a `belongsTo` relationship in the `deal` model and then doing a nested with like so: `$users = Users::with('deals.venue')->all();` but that does not work because the deal table does not have a foreign key to a venue. This is because a deal can be applied to multiple venues.

I am aware of the fact that this is very easily achievable using normal database queries, but for the way our API works it is essential to use the eloquent `with` relation function as our URL setup looks for includes that way.

TLDR: How to eager load nested three way pivot table relations.

Comment: Hello. Wondering if you have found a solution? I have also solved this by creating a model over the pivot table. But wondering if its possible without creating a new model?

Answer (score 2):

I would sugest you to treat the pivot table as another model (Redeem). Then make one-to-many relationships with the others tables/models (Deal/Venue/User) so you could just make your query using Eloquent like this to lazy load the objects you need:

```php
$redeems = User::find($id)->redeems;
$redeems->load(['venue','deal']);

return $redeems;
```

To format the data/response in an exact way you can use [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources) if your using 5.5. Or [Fractal](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-fractal) for 5.4 or below.

Comment: Naturally I thank you for your answer, but I must confess that I have indeed fixed the problem like you suggested. However, for the sake of argument I posted the question here anyway. In a way it feels a bit like cheating this way. Furthermore, now you can't use fancy eloquent functions like `attach` and/or `sync`, right? I was just wondering whether there was an other way.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you have a one-to-many relationship between deals and venues where you want to get a specific venue. Normally, you would create a hasMany() or belongsToMany() relationship in your deals model, then if you want to filter the venues further, you would write an Eloquent subquery like so:

```
// Gets first venue of deals
Users::with('deals', 'deals.venues' => function ($query) {
    $query->first();
})->all();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The relationship between `deals` and `venues` is many-to-many. A deal can be redeemable at multiple venues and venues can offer multiple different deals. Therefore, what you are proposing won't work because there is another pivot table (`deals_venue`) connecting those two.

Comment: Let me rephrase: what you are proposing works, but then I will receive ALL venues that offer that deal, not the specific venue where the deal is redeemed. The relationship between venues and deals does not really matter for my question, which is why I omitted it from my initial question.